# Отобразить дату создания файла в Label

Tags: c#, winforms, label, richtextbox

При нажатии `Button` который открывает файлы `.rtf` в `RichTextBox` должна появится дата создания этого файла в `Label`, как это сделать?

```
private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Rich Text Format | *.rtf";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label1.Text=System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(ofd.FileName).ToString();
```